# Why scanf overrides previously readed unsigned char variables with 0?

Tags: c, windows, scanf, mingw, unsigned-char

I tried to read several `unsigned char` values through `scanf` and found some strange bug. During the second call of `scanf`, first `unsigned char` variable gets overridden with 0. But writing `scanf(" %hhu", &second);` will cause override of the second `unsigned char` variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned char first, second;
    printf("Type first unsigned char variable: ");
    scanf("%hhu", &first);
    printf("first = %hhu\n", first);
    printf("Type second unsigned char variable: ");
    scanf("%hhu", &second);
    printf("first = %hhu\n", first);
    printf("second = %hhu\n", second);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler details:

gcc-core (gcc-5.1.0-tdm-1-core)

binutils (binutils-2.24-1-mingw32-bin)

mingwrt (mingwrt-3.20-2-mingw32-dev, mingwrt-3.20-2-mingw32-dll)

w32api (w32api-3.17-2-mingw32-dev)

P.S. Using `%hu` or `%u` makes no difference.

Comment: Could you please specify compiler version you have used and also parameters you passed to it, like optimization level etc.

Comment: It's most likely that second follows in address from first. So %hhu may be being interpreted as %hu. hhu is a C99 extension thus the question from j2ko about compiler version.

Comment: It's just mingw gnu gcc compiler with no special inputs

Comment: MinGW uses the Microsoft library, and the Microsoft C library is probably still C90 rather than C99 or later, so it probably doesn't handle the `hh` size modifier correctly.

Comment: Please edit that information into the question, and then delete the comment.

Comment: I can confirm that the Microsoft implementation of format functions does not recognizer `%hhu`, but I'm not in front of a Windows installation, so I wouldn't be able to test. You could try to write 65535 in `second` and see if it prints back 255 for both variables. If so, the conclusion is that you can't use `scanf` (or any variant thereof) to read `unsigned char` values on Windows.

Comment: zneak, it works exactly like you said!

Comment: use [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/) instead of whatever weird old mingw buggy version you have

Comment: @zneak *on this particular implementation, not Windows

Comment: @M.M, I said the Microsoft implementation.

Comment: @zneak you said "the conclusion is that you can't [do this] on Windows", when in fact the conclusion is that you can't do this on particular implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have an old, buggy version of MinGW.

Instead you can use [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/).  The project was forked in part due to the fact that the original project was unwilling to fix bugs like this, preferring to blame other parties.

Once using that compiler, use `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` compiler switch to get conforming mode (it still defaults to Microsoft compatibility mode unfortunately).